# Enviar la información recogida en un input a otro input situado en otra ventana con javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, text, ventana

Estoy intentado enviar la información recogida en un input type text a otro igual situado en otra ventana hija. Usando javaScript. No soy capaz de encontrar la manera de llamar a el codigo hijo.html desde el padre.El problema esta en la funcion enviar texto. Muchas gracias de antemano.

padre.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Saludo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="crearVentana1()">crear Ventana 1</button>
    <input type="text" id="inputText">
    <input type="button" id="botonText" onclick="enviartexto()" value="Enviar">




  <script >
var nuevaVentana1;

function crearVentana1(){
nuevaVentana1 = window.open('hijo.html')

}

function enviartexto(){
  var texto = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  nuevaVentana1.inputText2=texto;

}

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

hijo.html

```
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>VENTANA 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" id="inputText2"  readonly="readonly">

  <p id="parHijo1"></p>
  <input type="text" id="hijo">

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema hay que entender un poco más a fondo el funcionamiento de la web. Una vez una página está abierta, no va a actualizarse automáticamente a menos que la configures para eso, usando algo como un *Web Socket*. Es decir, si abres `hijo.html`, no importa cómo envíes datos desde `padre.html`, ya que hijo no está configurada para recibir datos.

Ahora, una solución práctica para lo que buscas, sería enviar el texto como un `query string` al pulsar `enviar`, de esta forma:

```js
var nuevaVentana1;
function enviartexto(){
  var texto = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  url = 'hijo.html?texto=' + texto
  nuevaVentana = window.open(url)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Saludo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="inputText">
    <input type="button" id="botonText" onclick="enviartexto()" value="Enviar">

  </body>
</html>
```

Y en `hijo.html` usar el query string para llenar el input:

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
document.querySelector('#hijo').value = params.get('texto');
```

```html
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>VENTANA 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" id="inputText2"  readonly="readonly">

  <p id="parHijo1"></p>
  <input type="text" id="hijo">

  </body>
</html>
```